# What happens if I select two tables with no WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a technical interview last week, and my interviewer asked me what happens if I run the following query:

`SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2`

I think I answered it correctly, but it wasn't an in-depth answer.

I said that I would select all the columns in both tables. For example if tbl1 has 3 columns, and tbl2 has 4 columns. The result set would have 7 columns.

Then he asked me why 7? and I said because I was selecting everything from each table.

That was a bad answer, but I couldn't think of anything else.

To cut to the chase, after the interviewed I executed the latter statement using two tables.

Table A, had 3 animal: dog, cat and elephant.

Table B had 2 names: Mat and Beth

This is the result set that I  got after the statement being executed:

```
*********************************************
| id_tbl1 | name_tbl1 | id_tbl2 | name_tbl2 |
*********************************************
|   1     |  dog      |    1    | Mat       |
|   2     |  cat      |    1    | Mat       |
|   3     |  elephant |    1    | Mat       |
|   1     |  dog      |    2    | Beth      |
|   2     |  cat      |    2    | Beth      |
|   3     |  elephant |    2    | Beth      |
*********************************************
```

So my question is, why does the statement behaves like that?

In other words:

Why does the Table B's records repeat themselves until I reach the end of table A, and then it starts all over again?

How would you have answered the question in a way that it would've "WOW'd" the interviewer?

Comment: They wee probably looking for the term "cross join" or "cartesian product". Also could have mentioned ANSI 89 vs ANSI 92 join syntax.

Comment: It behaves like this because you mentioned no criteria for join. so it's like `ON 1=1` - which means every line matches every line. But the exact terms this is called are the ones @MartinSmith mentioned.

Comment: as Martin Smith said, its producing the cross join ( product ) of both tables. So to say Y x X rows will be putout... or for your "WOW answer" you should have said: "for doing those, you shall be punished by a slow "explain query" death.

Comment: The first part of your question is talking about the number of *columns*, and you'd be correct at 7. But your actual experiment seems to be dealing with the number of *rows*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for pointing that out, but beyond rows and columns I wanted to know the logic behind the statement. Now I know that it is because of the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do a select like this, all rows in one resultset are joined to all rows in the other resultset (Cartesian Product).

So you get a list of all rows of the first table with the first row of the second table, Then all entries for the second row and so on. The order may be an implementation detail. Not sure if it is defined that the first order is by the first table, it might be different across implementations.
If you join three tables (or more), then the same happens with all rows of all tables. This, of course, is not only for tables, but for any result set from joins.

Answer (score 5):

The result will be a cartisian product
take a look at this example

[SQL Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16111/1)

You can see there are two tables one has 5 records and the other has 4 and the result is 20 records. Means 5 * 4 = 20 instead of 5 + 4 = 9 as you are assuming.

Table1

```
| IDX |   VAL |
---------------
|   1 | 1val1 |
|   1 | 1val2 |
|   2 | 2val1 |
|   2 | 2val2 |
|   2 | 2val3 |
```

Table2

```
| ID | POINTS |
---------------
|  1 |      2 |
|  2 |     10 |
|  3 |     21 |
|  4 |     29 |
```

Result of below query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 , Table2


| IDX |   VAL | ID | POINTS |
-----------------------------
|   1 | 1val1 |  1 |      2 |
|   1 | 1val1 |  2 |     10 |
|   1 | 1val1 |  3 |     21 |
|   1 | 1val1 |  4 |     29 |
|   1 | 1val2 |  1 |      2 |
|   1 | 1val2 |  2 |     10 |
|   1 | 1val2 |  3 |     21 |
|   1 | 1val2 |  4 |     29 |
|   2 | 2val1 |  1 |      2 |
|   2 | 2val1 |  2 |     10 |
|   2 | 2val1 |  3 |     21 |
|   2 | 2val1 |  4 |     29 |
|   2 | 2val2 |  1 |      2 |
|   2 | 2val2 |  2 |     10 |
|   2 | 2val2 |  3 |     21 |
|   2 | 2val2 |  4 |     29 |
|   2 | 2val3 |  1 |      2 |
|   2 | 2val3 |  2 |     10 |
|   2 | 2val3 |  3 |     21 |
|   2 | 2val3 |  4 |     29 |
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing yourself by running an example with two tables that have identical fields.  You are referring to a Union, which will combine the values of 1 table with another, and using your example this would give you 3 + 4 = 7 results.

The comma separated FROM statement is doing JOIN, which will go through all values in Table X and pair them with all the values of Table Y.  This would result in Size of X * Size of Y results, and using your example this would be 3 * 4 = 12.